# Defining a std::map with an undefined comparison function compiles and links, which surprises me

Tags: c++, c++11

In std::map, c++11, a function (pointer) specifying the key comparison function may be supplied as an optional parameter. While fiddling around with some code that does so, I got some results from the compiler that I didn't expect. I tried both g++ and clang++. As they both agree, I'm guessing the compilers are good, and I'm confused.

If I declare a std::map-type object in which the comparison function template parameter is specified, but then don't actually define the comparison function, the code still compiles and links and I see no warnings.

I compiled with -std=c++11 -O0 -Wall -Wextra

```
#include <map>

typedef std::map<int, int, bool(*)(int, int)> Objs;

int main() {

#if 0
  // Compiles and links as expected.
  Objs objs{[](int a, int b) {
    return a < b;
  }};
#endif

#if 1
  // FIXME The lambda definition for the key-comparing function is
  // missing; why does this compile and link?
  Objs objs;
#endif

  objs.emplace(99997, 4210124);
  (void)objs;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why won't it? It uses a value-initialized function pointer (i.e., a null pointer) as the comparator. Of course, when you try to run this in a way that requires the comparator to be used...bad things will happen, since it's UB.

Comment: Add another call to `emplace` and see how well your code runs.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting a single element into a map is not going to need to use the comparator (it's one element, with what it should be compared?).

Adding a second one will enter the UB realm.

(formally I think even adding one element is already UB as the standard doesn't specify exactly when and how many times the comparator function is called: not calling in case of a single element seems very reasonable, but calling it just for fun passing the same element twice I think doesn't violate C++ rules).

Note of course that even entering UB doesn't imply a crash... UB is UB and anything than happen (including nothing, unfortunately).